# Xcode items greyed out in the Document Outline

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been using iCloud to 'sync' Xcode projects I'm working on from my laptop to my desktop.  It doesn't seem to work that well unfortunately. I opened up a project today on the desktop that I worked on the laptop yesterday.

If I open the file on the desktop certain buttons and labels in the storyboard are missing. Looking at the document ouline I can see these but they are greyed out (see pic). However when I when I build the file, they appear as normal in the simulator.
 Any idea why or how to get them showing up normally?[image] (If I open this up on the laptop these aren't greyed out and all looks normal)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Items in the Document Outline become greyed out when they are not installed for the size class that you have selected at the bottom center of the storyboard view.

[image: size class selector]

You can see if the item is installed by selecting the item in the Document Outline and opening up the Attributes inspector.

Uninstalled:

[image]
[image]

Installed:

[image]
[image]