# Issue loading storyboard in interface builder

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, interface-builder, xcode-storyboard

I am building an app in Xcode 7.3.1 and it runs on devices and the simulator just fine, displaying the cells in my collection view.. but in interface builder the collection view cells do not appear..

I can't state how to recreate this scenario as it seemed to bug out like this after some changes I made in code a while ago.. before that it was displaying in interface builder just fine!

There should be two prototype collectionViewCells displaying on the view controller scene.

<s>From my research it seems to be a documented visual bug but I have not yet found a solution to it.</s>

No amount of 'cleaning/building' and closing and reopening the xcode project seems to fix this..

[image: interface builder not loading collection view cells]

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED!!**

The answer, [as described in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27380910/xcode-items-greyed-out-in-the-document-outline), is that the collectionview and its respective attributes did not have their appropriate size classes installed.

This is evident by the fact that the collectionview and labels in the screenshot below are greyed out.

[image: xcode navigator]

Using the advice from the SO link I solved my problem by selecting each greyed out component and then making sure that I ticked the top box labelled 'installed' in the attribute inspector.

[image: attribute inspector]

After doing this and remaking the constraints my storyboard was back to normal!

[image: interface builder]